# Python Socket Programming Error: OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use

Tags: python, macos, sockets

Im trying to follow sentdex socket programming in python tutorial. 
Here is my server code:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.bind((socket.gethostname(), 12345 ))

sock.listen(5)

while True:
    clientsocket, address = sock.accept()
    print(f"Connection established from {address}")
    clientsocket.send(bytes("Server says HI","utf-8"))
```

Here is my client code:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.bind((socket.gethostname(), 12345 ))

m = sock.recv(1024)

print(m.decode('utf-8'))

sock.close()
```

Im using a macbook air with python 3.6.7 in a virtualenv.
I first run the server.py program, and then the client.py program.
Running client.py gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 5, in <module>
    sock.bind((socket.gethostname(), 12345 ))
OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

Sentdex was running the code in windows and it worked but I dont see what I am doing wrong here conceptually. Please help!

Comment: `sock.bind` -> `sock.connect` in client code.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works, I guess I need to read the documentation more haha.